# What's the algorithm behind opencv::pointPolygonTest?

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv

I am using OpenCV to test whether a point lies inside or on the edge of a polygon. I was wondering what the algorithm of the function is called. I understand, that it's working with the orientation of triangles created with two consecutive vertices and the test-point, but sadly I didn't find the proper name of the algorithm. I am familiar with the ray-casting and winding number algortihm to test whether a point is inside a polygon, but I feel like the OpenCV-function implements a different algorithm.

If anyone knows what algorithm is used in the opencv::pointPolygonTest function, please let me know. The name (and maybe even a reference to a description of the algorithm) would help me a lot!

If my assumptions stated above are wrong, please don't be shy to correct me, I'm relatively new to  computer vision.

Thank you in advance!

PS: [This](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga1a539e8db2135af2566103705d7a5722) is the OpenCV documentation of the function and the source code can be found [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/geometry.cpp#L95).

Comment: line 95 https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/68d15fc62edad980f1ffa15ee478438335f39cc3/modules/imgproc/src/geometry.cpp (there is no reference to any algorithm...)

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Exactly. That's why I'm asking if anyone knows the algorithm of this function

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon it's the very first one. please look before asking.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks for your comment, it appears to be some kind of ray casting algorithm even though it's implemented by computing the orientation of the triangle rather than comparing the slopes

Comment: that is not my reading of the source code. it clearly tests all segments of the *contour/polygon*, discards them if they're above/below/left of the point in question, and analyzes those that are *right* of the point.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Exactly. First it tests the contour whether it is above/below/left of the point and afterwards it analyzes those that are right of the point. The analysis is done by computing the orientation of the triangle (which is done by computing the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Computational_geometry)). Thank you for your help!

Comment: again, there is no "triangle", which implies 3 corners. it's a polygon consisting of lines, meaning an arbitrary number of corners.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Sorry, I should've been clearer. Obviously the algorithm itself is made for checking polygons. But on [line 122](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/68d15fc62edad980f1ffa15ee478438335f39cc3/modules/imgproc/src/geometry.cpp#L122) two consecutive points are extracted (one contour of the polygon) and then the check on which side the point is, is implemented by computing the [orientation of 3 ordered points](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/orientation-3-ordered-points/) (that's what I meant, when i was talking about triangles).

Comment: that... looks like the so-called "cross product". the goal is to figure out, for some point, on which side of a line the point sits.